# Android build beta APK and release APK via circleci

Tags: android, google-play, apk, circleci, fastlane

How to build a beta version of APK and a release version of APK via circleci at the same time.

Is there a way to generate two apk files by configuring circleci's configuration file `config.yml`? The beta version of apk can be released via fabric, and the release version of apk can be uploaded to Google play.

Now, I can only post an same apk via the fabric and Google play platforms.

Or is there another way to build two apks at the same time, can they be installed on one phone at the same time?

I am grateful for any ideas!

Comment: I guess, you are looking for something like Flavors in android: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants

Comment: You could use something like [Fastlane](https://docs.fastlane.tools/)